# Animation auto reset when scrolling up and down in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have create an apps with a timeline like where the function is when scrolling up and down, the content should be animated. I want to build my apps just like this page (http://www.bbc.com/future/bespoke/20140304-how-big-is-space-interactive/ ).

I've put 2 trigger box on top and bottom of the canvas. 2 Animations were created, so when the content from below hit the trigger box when scrolling, it should be animated to large size (animator 'planettolarge'). So does when the content hit the trigger box at the top, it should be back to smaller size back (animator 'planettosmall').

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrKZS.png)

The problem is, how to set the animation to be large size mode when the content is center on the canvas when scrolled from top. Because the animation is normal when the page is scrolled from the bottom.

Here is the simplest I have tried so far since I'm a beginner in Unity. I would appreciate so much if you drop any solution here. TQ =)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class trigger : MonoBehaviour
{

   Animator anim_roket;
   Animator anim_planet;
   private BoxCollider2D triggerup;
   private BoxCollider2D triggerdown;

   void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
   {
       switch (col.tag)
       {
           case "triggerup":
               GetComponent<Animator>().Play("planettosmall");
               break;

           case "triggerdown":
               GetComponent<Animator>().Play("planettolarge");
               break;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i recommend is to use the animator component and triggers instead of two animations, when you reach your trigger point you fire the animation trigger and the animation starts running.

first create an empty state and set many transitions to each f your animations with a bool parameter, if any scripts sets or clears that parameter the animation will be fired or stopped, remember to reset the animation time to the beginning every time you stop any animation so it can start from the beginning again.

see this tutorials to get a better idea, I hope it helps

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeZkctmoBPw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7EIp-OqVyk